# How to change the Android emulator phone number

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

Is it possible to change the phone number of mine on the android emulator, just like Genymotion which is always show me 1-555-521-xxx number. any ideas would be nice and appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, emulator doesn't have working phone number because they don't have SIM. Anyway, [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16382341/2821954) explains the dummy phone number that the emulator use.

Comment: Thank you for your information. i understand that emulator does not have real phone number, it is dummy. what i want to asking is that how to change that one ?